# C code reading a file including two columns (numbers) and print them with array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a question about c code reading two columns in a file and print them.

I have a a bond.txt file including two columns like,

```
1 2
1 3
1 25
1 6682
4 5
4 6
4 13117
7 21
7 24
```

I code the following below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define ROW 10
#define COL 1

int readresults(FILE *results, FILE *fout, int score[][COL]);

int main()
{
        FILE *f=fopen("bond.txt", "r");
        FILE *fout=fopen("out.txt", "w");
        int score[ROW][COL];
        readresults(f, fout, score);

        printf("score[5][1] = %d\n", score[5][1]);

}

readresults(FILE *results, FILE *fout, int score[][COL])
{
        int row, col, item, i, j;
        for(row=0; row<ROW; row++)
        {
                col = 0;

                item = fscanf(results, "%d%d", &score[row][col], &score[row][col+1]);
                fprintf(fout, "%d %d", score[row][col], score[row][col+1]);
                printf("[%d %d]=%d [%d %d]=%d\n", row, col, score[row][col], row, col+1,     score[row][col+1]);
                fprintf(fout, "\n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

When I looked at the output file. The items have no problem. However, the print in main function is different.

For example, in output file, `score[5][1] = 6`, but in main function, `score[5][1] = 4` on my screen.

Comment: please format the 2 columns properly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the **COL** constant to 2

Your matrix have 2 columns, so you must define it with COL = 2

Comment: I thought that the index start with 0, so the COL = 1 includes 0 and 1 which are total 2 indexes. Thank you.